# "You made too few changes to the post to improve it?"

Tags: support, edits

[image]

I don't remember seeing this before. I just edited a block of code to be indented four spaces, because it was obviously formatted terribly without the code block formatting.

Eeeeek! Is this new? I thought 2k+ users weren't limited on how minor their edits could be....

Searching meta for "You made too few changes to the post to improve it" did not bring up any results, and I've never seen this before, so I suppose it's new?

**EDIT**: Supposedly, [other people can](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18097596/revisions). Huh? [possible-bug](/questions/tagged/possible-bug)?

**EDIT2**: Wait, the original revision now contains blockquotes. It didn't when I saw it first. The OP must have edited in the grace period. Hmm, maybe that's why! Maybe it has something to do with editing in the grace period while I was editing. Is it a reword of the "your edit must improve the post more than the previous revision," maybe?

Comment: Now let me check... well, looks like it's not activated on Meta. ;)

Comment: Best guess: it's intended for <2K users to ease the burden of "too minor" rejections and bug caused it to be applied to all users.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yep, probably something like that.

Comment: [For the lazy!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097596/what-is-in-following-script)

Comment: Seems like that restriction does not apply to suggested edits...

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby *Very* odd.

Comment: @CRUSADER How did you do that 1-char edit? It didn't trigger the error for you? :O

Comment: no-repro here..

Comment: Nope, also no repro for me...that's odd...first I thought it might be because of a missing question mark, but I can edit rev 1 just fine.

Comment: @Doorknob no error whatsoever on that edit..

Comment: Gah! Am I the only one? I'll try doing a minor edit on some other random post....

Comment: @Doorknob: No, rollback to rev1 and try on that one again. If that fails (again), please C&P the whole edit.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I'm afraid that user might get confused as to what's going on... and it might CW the post :P

Comment: @Doorknob: CWing it is only an improvement, that post should be deleted anyway in my opinion. ^^

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby Heh, okay, I'll try.

Comment: Maybe it's affecting only 10K+ users! :/

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby Wait, the original revision now contains blockquotes. It didn't when I saw it first. The OP must have edited in the grace period. Hmm, maybe that's why! Maybe it has something to do with editing in the grace period while I'm edited. Is it a reword of the "your edit must improve the post more than the previous revision," maybe?

Comment: @Doorknob: That would be an explanation, some sort of collision is quite possible (maybe the OP even managed to format it correctly as code, your edit came along, system sees it sucks, OP changes it to blockquotes)...or it's simply the wrong message.

Comment: @Doorknob: Nope, even with the blockquotes stripped out I can not reproduce it (see rev9). So it was most likely a collision and the wrong message or some such.

Comment: Jeez I was wondering what "Bobby" was doing editing the linked question so many times... now I know.

Comment: Edit conflicts are causing lots of headache, maybe they finally put something in place to prevent such conflicts... though in such case, the message can be improved.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Possibly. I wonder why they didn't say anything about this though... also blue wizard got a ton of clicks for some reason :P

Comment: @Doorknob lol re the wizard! As for the team, they do lots of silent changes sometimes to test things.

Comment: [hrm.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1472346#1472346)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit 2 is correct – it's the same message, but it was changed about 6 months ago during the general overhaul of the various validation/editing message.

Answer (score 1):

This is broken. I just made one substantial edit, but forgot to remove the tag from the title. When I went back to fix up the tag, I got this message and was prevented from doing it.

Bad idea.